# Run terminal and show the output

Tags: c, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I want to run a console application from my web browser remotely. It will be something like Onion Terminal or Shell In The Box. But, I do not want to run the unix terminal. I want to run my own console application through the web browser. How can I do this? Ideally, I would like to modify Onion Terminal or shell in the box to achieve this. But the C code for these two tools are way too complicated for me since I have never done network related programming in C before.

Operating System: Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) 64-bit

Comment: Please be more precise in what you want. Do you want to embedded one of those terminals in your web browser? Do you want your web browser to spawn their executables? What do you mean by remotely?

Comment: I want to have a button on the web page. When I click on that button it should run a console application on the remote machine. I should be able to view the console application's "terminal" on my web browser. If you see Onion Terminal, it runs the terminal of the remote machine on the web browser. You can basically see everything that is happening on the terminal through your web browser. I want the same thing but instead of running the terminal of the remote machine, I want to run my own console application on the remote machine.